# How to prevent apctest from shutting down the UPS immediately when performing a battery calibration?

Tags: ups

I am running an APC SMT1500RMI2U connected to a Linux server via serial cable. On the Linux server, the UPS is managed by `apcupsd` and the associated utilities. `apcupsd` communicates with the UPS using the MODBUS protocol.

From time to time, I'd like to perform a battery calibration of the UPS via `apctest`. But every time I do that, `apctest` shuts down the server (nearly) immediately. This really sucks because I stumble across that misbehavior every time I try it. I just have killed not only the server, but 6 running VMs with it due to that test.

What I am doing wrong? What do I need to do to perform the battery calibration without `apctest` shutting down the UPS immediately?

Additional information:

- Debian 11 (bullseye), amd64, vanilla (no custom kernel or something like that), up to date.
- `apcupsd` and the associated utilities (e.g., `apcaccess`) work without issues.
- The batteries are definitely not that worn out; when I pull the plug, the server runs at least 20 minutes without problems.
- However, as described above, `apctest` shuts down the UPS / the server immediately after it has started the runtime calibration.
- Of course, I always stop `apcupsd` before using `apctest` (`apctest` won't start anyway if `apcupsd` runs).
- The version of `apcupsd` is 3.14.14.

The following shows the output of `apcaccess`:

```
root@cerberus ~ # apcaccess
APC      : 001,039,0917
DATE     : 2023-08-08 17:17:11 +0200
HOSTNAME : cerberus
VERSION  : 3.14.14 (31 May 2016) debian
UPSNAME  : APCUPS
CABLE    : Custom Cable Smart
DRIVER   : MODBUS UPS Driver
UPSMODE  : Stand Alone
STARTTIME: 2023-08-08 17:16:37 +0200
MODEL    : Smart-UPS 1500
STATUS   : ONLINE
LINEV    : 233.2 Volts
LOADPCT  : 26.6 Percent
LOADAPNT : 20.1 Percent
BCHARGE  : 100.0 Percent
TIMELEFT : 51.0 Minutes
MBATTCHG : -1 Percent
MINTIMEL : -1 Minutes
MAXTIME  : 120 Seconds
OUTPUTV  : 233.2 Volts
DWAKE    : 0 Seconds
DSHUTD   : 0 Seconds
ITEMP    : 27.9 C
BATTV    : 27.1 Volts
LINEFREQ : 50.0 Hz
OUTCURNT : 1.31 Amps
NUMXFERS : 0
TONBATT  : 0 Seconds
CUMONBATT: 0 Seconds
XOFFBATT : N/A
SELFTEST : NO
STATFLAG : 0x05000008
MANDATE  : 2017-03-01
SERIALNO : AS1709331884
BATTDATE : 2023-04-15
NOMOUTV  : 230 Volts
NOMPOWER : 1000 Watts
NOMAPNT  : 1500 VA
FIRMWARE : UPS 09.4 / 00.5
END APC  : 2023-08-08 17:17:11 +0200
```